# Upper bound for $\mathrm{tr}\Big((P + I)^{-1}(P + d uu^T)(P + I)^{-1}\Big)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, trace

I am interested in the following function,
$$
f(P, u) := \mathrm{tr}\Big((P + I)^{-1}(P + d uu^T)(P + I)^{-1}\Big).
$$
Above, $P$ is a symmetric positive definite real matrix and $u$ is a vector with unit norm. Here $d$ denotes the dimension. It is a positive integer.

I can use the bound
$uu^T \leq I$ in the positive definite ordering and I obtain
$$
f(P, u) \leq \mathrm{tr}\Big((P + I)^{-1}(P + d I)(P + I)^{-1}\Big),
$$
however I do not believe this bound can be attained for a unit vector $u$ (simply because $uu^T$ is rank 1).

Is there a better characterization of the following maximal quantity?
$$
\sup_{u : \|u\| = 1} f(P, u)
$$

Comment: You didn't say anything about $d$. Is $d$ a positive constant?

Comment: You're right. It is the dimension. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}[(P + I)^{-1}(P &+ duu^T)(P + I)^{-1}] 
\\&= 
\operatorname{tr}[(P + I)^{-1}P(P + I)^{-1} + d(P + I)^{-1}uu^T(P + I)^{-1}]
\\ & = 
\operatorname{tr}[(P + I)^{-1}P(P + I)^{-1}] + d\operatorname{tr}[(P + I)^{-1}uu^T(P + I)^{-1}]
\\ & = 
\operatorname{tr}[(P + I)^{-1}(P + I)^{-1}P] + d\operatorname{tr}[u^T(P + I)^{-1}(P + I)^{-1}u]
\\ & = 
\operatorname{tr}[(P + I)^{-2}P] + d\,u^T(P + I)^{-2}u
\\&= 
\operatorname{tr}[(P + I)^{-2}P] + d\cdot \|(P + I)^{-1}u\|^2.
\end{align}
$$
So, if $d > 0$, it's clear that
$$
\sup_{u:\|u\|=1} f(P,u) = \operatorname{tr}[(P + I)^{-2}P] + d \sup_{u:\|u\|=1} \|(P + I)^{-1}u\|^2.
$$
Because $P$ is symmetric an positive definite, this turns out to be easy to compute in terms of the eigenvalues (which equal the singular values) of $P$. We have
$$
\sup_{u:\|u\|=1} \|(P + I)^{-1}u\|^2 = \frac{1}{(1 + \lambda_{\min}(P))^2},
$$
leading to the overall maximum
$$
\sup_{u:\|u\|=1} f(P,u) = \operatorname{tr}[(P + I)^{-2}P] + \frac{d}{(1 + \lambda_{\min}(P))^2}.
$$
If you prefer, we can rewrite $\lambda_\min(P) = \|P^{-1}\|^{-1}$, where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the spectral norm.

Comment: I think you're missing a square above. You should have the square of the operator norm (In other words, you will obtain $1/(1 + \lambda)^2$.)

Comment: @DrewBrady You're right, edited my answer